# avoid printing the index of the array?

Tags: php

I'm looping through a multidimensional/nest array and I get the following result, however I want to get rid of the "1": index numbers in front of each array.

```
{"1":{"adjacencies":[{"nodeTo":"2"},{"nodeTo":"5"}],"data":  {"$color":"#EBB056","$type":"star"},"id":1,"name":"rootWarbler<\/label>"},
"2":{"adjacencies":[{"nodeTo":"4"},{"nodeTo":"3"}],"data":{"$color":"#EBB056","$type":"star"},"id":2,"name":"rootJuniper tree<\/label>"},
"3":{"adjacencies":[null],"data":{"$color":"#EBB056","$type":"star"},"id":3,"name":"rootPuff Bird<\/label>"},
"4":{"adjacencies":[{"nodeTo":"5"},{"nodeTo":"3"}],"data":{"$color":"#EBB056","$type":"star"},"id":4,"name":"rootJackRabbit<\/label>"},
"5":{"adjacencies":[null],"data":{"$color":"#EBB056","$type":"star"},"id":5,"name":"rootMountain Lion<\/label>"},
"6":{"adjacencies":[{"nodeTo":"1"}],"data":{"$color":"#EBB056","$type":"star"},"id":6,"name":"rootBobcat<\/label>"}}
```

here is my while loop

```
$previd = -1;
 while($row=$result->FetchRow())
{
$id= (float)$row['n_id']; 
$name = $row['name'];
$color1 = $row['color'];
$type1 = $row['type'];
$to= (float)$row['goingto']; 
$thumb =$row['thumb']; //image path


if ($previd != $id) {
    $previd = $id; 
    if ($previd != -1) {
        array_push($array,$node);
    }

    $node[$id] = array(
        "adjacencies" => array(),
        "data" => array(
                "$"."color" => $color1,
                "$"."type" => $type1 
            ),
        "id" => $id,
        "name" => "<img src='".$thumb."' height='25' width='25' alt='root'/><label>".$name."</label>");
}


if ($to != null) { 
    $node[$id]["adjacencies"][]=array("nodeTo" => "$to");
}


}
print_r($node);
```

Comment: you use `json_encode()` here right?

Comment: I don't understand. What do you want your result to be like after getting rid of the 1's ? (please edit in your question)

Comment: Since when does print_r output JSON?

Comment: actually i need the index off because im encoding it via json

Answer (score 1):

I really don't understand how come you get a very perfect json string without using `json_encode()` but I will try my best to get near on what you really want

```
echo json_encode(array_values($array));
```

where the `$array` is the array that you want to convert to JSON without the index numbers

so it means it will be like this

```
 echo json_encode(array_values($node));
```

In this case you need to `array_values()` use http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php

Comment: i actually do use json, sorry i mistyped.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say with confidence, but what about

```
for($node as $n)
{
    print_r($n);
}
```

or

```
for($node as $k=>$n)
{
    print_r($n);
}
```

But really, `print_r` is more of a debugging tool than an output formatting tool.

Edit: Now that I see your comment regarding JSON... [**use JSON**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php): [json_encode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

```
print(json_encode($node));
```

If you're still getting the array indices with that, try something like

```
print(implode("\n", array_map("json_encode", $node)));
```

Comment: This just prints the $node out and he's not getting rid of anything?

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld: Actually, this gets rid of the implicit array indexing that is causing the 1,2,3,4,... to print out from the `print_r` statement.  Funny, I would have thought the bestprogrammerintheworld would have known that...

Comment: LOL :-) Aha. That's what he wanted. It didn't figure out the actual question.